# How can i login using email address in zend?

Tags: zend-framework

I have the situtation like , Admin should login as User  from Admin End. I have user email address which is username for my site.

I am using following code in login page.

```
...
$users = new Default_Model_DbTable_Users();
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($users->getAdapter(),'customers');
$authAdapter->setIdentityColumn('email')->setCredentialColumn('password');
$authAdapter->setIdentity($username)->setCredential(base64_encode($password));
$authAdapter->getDbSelect()->where('status = 1');
$result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
.....
```

Now I have to use only email address to login. I can check  whether ADMIN do the user login from admin end. Is it possible to login using email address ?. Kindly advice on this

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do?  Do you want an admin to be able to type a user's email address with no password to log in as that user?

Comment: @drew Thanks, Actually i have a button in admin end called "create order" which is under user management. When admin wants to create order in that particular user, admin will click that button to login as user , it will redirect to front end.In this situation, how can we do in zend ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to allow admin to log in as any user from the admin panel, you don't have to use `Zend_Auth::authenticate()` to check any credentials against the database.  All you really need to do is set up the identity like you do for a normal user login.

From admin you might do something like this:

```
$user = getUserInfoFromDatabase(); // get the user object used for Zend_Auth identity
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($user);
// redirect admin to user frontend
```

The only important thing is that whatever you `write()` to the storage, must be the EXACT same object/data you write to storage from your user login code.

It doesn't matter how the data gets there, as long as it is what your application requires to check identity.

Since your admin has already been authenticated and has permission to access a user account, you don't need to use `Zend_Auth::authenticate()` to validate the user email/password, you can skip that step and simply assign the identity for the admin directly to the session.

You may need to use separate session namespaces for admin and users if you are not already.

Hope that helps, let me know if I can clarify anything.  The part where you set the identity is probably short after `$result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);` in your code, probably inside `if ($result == true)`